# Partially deserialize a json object in a restful post call

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am trying to get a method in springmvc to accept a partial json string of an object, and have jackson automatically de-serialize it for me.
I can solve it by making a temporary object with only the attributes I want, or pass it in as a string and use Gson to desearialize it for me, but these feel hacky.  Is there any way to tell jackson how to do it?

Here is the controller snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/task", 
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    consumes="application/json")
public @ResponseBody String postTask(@RequestBody Task task){
    if(task.getId() == null){
        task.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
    }
    if(task.getDate_entered() == 0){
        task.setDate_entered(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    TaskDao.addTask(task);
    return "success";
}
```

And the task, a basic pojo:

```
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class Task {
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private long date_entered;
    private long finish_by;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    // Rest of the getters and setters
}
```

If you can't tell by my other spring related questions, I'm kind of flying blind, and can't figure out the proper google query for this one.

Thanks!

Comment: According to the Jackson documentation this behaviour should be standard. I.e. If there is no value for an attribute it's setter is not called but the object is still created. See http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/what-happens-if-a-property-is-missing

Comment: Oh no!  If thats the case then I am either using an older version or have it set up wrong.  I will try to confirm both.  Thanks

Comment: @Awalsh: aannnddd this morning it works as intended... not entirely sure what I changed to enable/disable it before.
I will try and figure out what changed and put that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@JsonIgnore`annotation  of jackson on the method (on setter for deserialization and on getter for serialization) or field, for which you want to ignore serialization and/or deserialization. e.g.
In your example, if you don't want to serialize `description`, then you can do,

```
@JsonIgnore
public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
 }
```

And you will see, that you won't get value of `description` in converted model.

Comment: Would this allow to pick what would be deserialized on the fly?
For instance you could pass in the UUID one time, then just the name the next?

Comment: With this configuration, NO. Because we annotate in the class definition itself and I think it won't be possible to change class definition on fly.